# How to add a catch statement to fix Unhandled promise rejection warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bcrypt

I am trying to add user authentication to my site. The register route on my page works perfectly but I receive an Unhandled promise rejection warning when I try to send a request to the login route.

I've tried adding `.catch(err => console.log(err));` and
`.catch(console.log("Something's gone wrong."));` to the end of both `.findOne().then()` and `.compare().then()`, but that didn't help.

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.passowrd;

  User.findOne({ email }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ email: "User not found" });
    }

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.passowrd).then(isMatch => {
      if (isMatch) {
        res.json({ msg: "Success" });
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ password: "Password incorrect" });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The code is supposed to simply send back a message that the passwords match, so I can later generate a token. I get this error:

```
(node:18152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, undefined
    at _async (/home/jok/code/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:286:46)
    at /home/jok/code/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:307:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.bcrypt.compare (/home/jok/code/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:306:20)
    at User.findOne.then.user (/home/jok/code/routes/api/users.js:64:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
(node:18152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18152) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: `.catch(console.log("Something's gone wrong."));` is wrong, you need to pass a callback to `catch`. Using `.catch(err => console.log(err));` in the two places you mentioned should work. Can you please update your code to show what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` occurs because you're not handling the Promise rejection, meaning that you're missing a `.catch` handler.

```
bcrypt.compare(password, user.passowrd).then(isMatch => {
  if (isMatch) {
    res.json({ msg: "Success" });
  } else {
    return res.status(400).json({ password: "Password incorrect" });
  }
})
.catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
});
```

In this particular case, it seems that `password` & `user.passowrd` are `undefined`. The latter probable because of a typo: `passowrd` => `password`.

So it's recommended to check that the arguments sent to your route are valid.

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.passowrd;

  if(!email || !password)
    return res.status(400).send('email & password are required');

  /* ... */
});
```

Since you're missing the `.catch` handler also on the `.findOne` `Promise`, it's always better to chain Promises instead of nesting them as you're doing. So here's the complete code:

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.passowrd;

    if (!email || !password)
        return res.status(400).send('email & password are required');

    User.findOne({ email })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(404)
                    .json({ message: "User not found" });
            }

            return bcrypt.compare(password, user.passowrd);
        })
        .then(isMatch => {

            if (typeof isMatch !== 'boolean')
                return; // result from `res.status(404)...`

            if (isMatch)
                return res.json({ message: "Success" });

            return res.status(400)
                .json({ message: "Password incorrect" });

        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
        });

 });
```

> I've tried adding .catch(err => console.log(err)); and
>   .catch(console.log("Something's gone wrong.")); to the end of both
>   .findOne().then() and .compare().then(), but that didn't help.

Either you didn't attach the handler correctly, or the warning was triggered in another code. But since the provided code does not have the `.catch` you mention, I can't confirm. Anyways, the above snippet won't trigger an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

Comment: What? That's the catch, the output of `internal server error`.... If you get that message, it means that the error was indeed catched. And that the answer is correct.

Comment: That worked. I added the `.catch` to the end of `.compare` and the promise was handled correctly. It kept skipping to the `catch` and outputting `internal server error` because I was giving it bad data. I've marked the question as answered.

Comment: It's better if you don't add a `.catch` to compare but return the promise instead, and have a single `.catch` like my snippet, but I'm glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    
    // Use your response
});
```

That is not necessary to use promises in simple logic.